# is it possible to have two submit button for one form?

Tags: python, html, web2py

I am using web2py to write a search engine like app. Is it possible to implement two submit button for one form such as google has two buttons "search" and "I am feeling lucky". Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but in PHP you'll find which button has been pressed (in a multi-button form) by checking if the `$_POST` array contains a key named after the name of the pressed button. Do you have anything like a `$_POST` array in webpy?

Comment: Be very wary of MS Internet Explorer — some old versions will send the values of ALL submit buttons instead of the one that was clicked.

Comment: @detly Being wary of IE is a default state for any web developer. You spend about 25% of your time designing a website, then 75% of your time getting it to work in IE.

Comment: @Lattyware - ahaha, indeed :) But in this case, I happen to know of a specific quirk to be wary of, so it's a slightly more precise paranoia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def search():
    form = FORM(INPUT(_type='text', _name='keywords'),
        INPUT(_type='submit', _value='Search'),
        INPUT(_type='submit', _value="I'm feeling lucky", _name='lucky'),
        _method='get')
    if request.vars.keywords:
        if request.vars.lucky:
            [code to return "I'm feeling lucky" results]
        else:
            [code to return regular results]
    return dict(form=form)
```

Giving a name to the "I'm feeling lucky" submit button causes its value to be submitted with the form, so you can check for its presence among the submitted variables and conditionally return a different response in that case.

Note, the `FORM()` helper defaults to using the post method, but because this is a search form, the above uses the get method.

You could also build the form manually in the view rather than using the `FORM()` helper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in the incoming request is the name of the pressed button.

Comment: This is a bad answer. How is it possible?

Comment: read carefully: "in the incoming request you have name of pressed button"

Answer (score 0):

For reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/a0hoswzJBYY has a solution when using the `SQLFORM.factory` helper instead of the `FORM` helper.